# Background only on parts of UINavigationBar

Tags: ipad, background, uinavigationbar, ios7.1

I want to set background to the navigation bar, but only at the one that is rounded by red rectangle. I do not want it on the other two, where says "Menú" and "Titulo Menu".

[image]

I use this code in AppDelegate class:

```
UIImage *navBarImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fondo.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImg 
  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

How can I do that? It is possible?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you initalize all of your NavBars in the storyboard? Or by code?

If you added them through the Storyboard, you can just link the red marked UINavBar to some Pointer in the code and just call:

```
[myNavbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:navBarImg] 
           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

So you don't change the Style of all NavBars, just the one you want.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Hi Berti, thanks for your answer. Navigation Bar that I add through the storyboard is that what says "Titulo Menu", but an above one is default bar where goes the time and level of battery. So as far as I know that default Nav Bar can't be linked to my class. Have you got some other suggestions? Thanks!